# VBA: Save workbook in XML but with the same workbook name

Tags: excel, vba

I am having excel (xlsm) file which I wanna export to XML using one of my schemas. BUT, I would like to have the same workbook name as my original file without editing it manually (as an export). I did this in macro recorder but some adjustment has to be done.

```
Sub Macro1()

  Range("Table1[Bestimmungsort]").Select
   ActiveWorkbook.XmlMaps("Report_Map").Export URL:= _
    "C:\XXX\YY\Downloads\000.xml"
End Sub
```

Comment: To get the name of a workbook use `ThisWorkbook.Name`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the next approach, please:

```
Dim Wb As Workbook
 Set Wb = ActiveWorkbook
 
 Wb.XmlMaps("Report_Map").Export url:= _
    "C:\XXX\YY\Downloads\" & left(Wb.Name, Len(Wb.Name) - 5) & ".xml"
```

Edited: Variant to allow picking of a folder path:

```
Dim Wb As Workbook, xDlg As FileDialog, xFdItem  as string
 Set Wb = ActiveWorkbook
 Set xDlg = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    If xDlg .Show Then
        xFdItem = xDlg .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
    Else
        Exit Sub
    End If
 Wb.XmlMaps("Report_Map").Export url:= _
       xFdItem  & left(Wb.Name, Len(Wb.Name) - 5) & ".xml"
```

Comment: This looks and works as it should be for me. Thanks a lot! It is nice and simple piece of code.

Comment: @Mirza: Glad I could help!

Comment: Sorry man!! One thing, how to get this promped window which gives an option to Save my output XML file somewhere else? In my case was "downloads" but is there possibility to make it dynamic and with possilibity to choose folder path?

Comment: @ FaneDuru haha =)  when you got time, aint super important for now. drive safely

Comment: @Mirza: Yes, it is. I will adapt my answer code... Adapted.

Comment: Amazing! Works better than ever. Have to learn VBA actually. Thanks man!